Sorting calendar plot with geom_segment() without overlapping
I am trying to do this calendar ggplot2.
So far, it works fine, but I want to make one adjustment, and I am not finding the way:

Overlapping of geom_segment() in num_months 2:5 in year 2021. For some reason, some geom_segment() are plotted in the same row as the same segment, and I cannot figure out where the problem is in the code. The last segment is num_months 2, and the year 2021 has three segments of three months each. The last two segments of num_months 3 and 4 are two segments overlapped. I think it may be due to the end_month being December, but I don't know how to fix that.

This is the output where it shows the overlapping in blue blocks:

data <- read_csv("country,num_months,start_month_year,end_month_year,B1,B1_p,year,start_month,end_month
2,1,6,6,3.3571016788482666,0.007681768853217363,2021,5,5
2,1,8,8,2.548985481262207,0.007373321335762739,2021,7,7
2,1,10,10,2.139772415161133,0.03452971577644348,2021,9,9
2,1,12,12,2.165775775909424,0.07796278595924377,2021,11,11
2,1,13,13,1.9506219625473022,0.09215697646141052,2021,12,12
2,1,23,23,2.7839596271514893,0.011407249607145786,2022,10,10
2,1,25,25,2.220555543899536,0.06181173026561737,2022,12,12
2,2,10,11,1.4871771335601807,0.06038494035601616,2021,9,10
2,2,12,13,2.0390524864196777,0.04265233874320984,2021,11,12
2,2,13,14,1.417211651802063,0.09348150342702866,2021,12,1
2,2,22,23,1.874699354171753,0.018470995128154755,2022,9,10
2,2,23,24,1.6757967472076416,0.028078539296984673,2022,10,11
2,3,6,8,1.334544062614441,0.05757715925574303,2021,5,7
2,3,8,10,1.2151446342468262,0.05723109096288681,2021,7,9
2,3,10,12,1.7102551460266113,0.03582938387989998,2021,9,11
2,3,11,13,1.6229373216629028,0.07926513999700546,2021,10,12
2,3,12,14,1.6802176237106323,0.04918825626373291,2021,11,1
2,3,13,15,1.417211651802063,0.09348150342702866,2021,12,2
2,3,22,24,1.3854548931121826,0.033461399376392365,2022,9,11
2,3,23,25,1.8822635412216187,0.01415294036269188,2022,10,12
2,4,8,11,1.1319600343704224,0.06593644618988037,2021,7,10
2,4,10,13,1.754726767539978,0.02880094014108181,2021,9,12
2,4,11,14,1.4533793926239014,0.08008415251970291,2021,10,1
2,4,12,15,1.6802176237106323,0.04918825626373291,2021,11,2
2,4,22,25,1.6274609565734863,0.011329303495585918,2022,9,12
2,5,6,10,1.0146392583847046,0.08948446065187454,2021,5,9
2,5,8,12,1.338212251663208,0.04161843657493591,2021,7,11
2,5,9,13,1.2212527990341187,0.0919371098279953,2021,8,12
2,5,10,14,1.5834165811538696,0.03494146466255188,2021,9,1
2,5,11,15,1.4533793926239014,0.08008415251970291,2021,10,2
2,5,12,16,1.4284441471099854,0.0697392150759697,2021,11,3
2,5,21,25,1.2466250658035278,0.035289958119392395,2022,8,12
2,6,6,11,0.9881601333618164,0.08719704300165176,2021,5,10
2,6,8,13,1.438501238822937,0.032221969217061996,2021,7,12
2,6,9,14,1.16400945186615,0.09187468141317368,2021,8,1
2,6,10,15,1.5834165811538696,0.03494146466255188,2021,9,2
2,6,11,16,1.294316291809082,0.09792502969503403,2021,10,3
2,6,12,17,1.4204859733581543,0.0546354204416275,2021,11,4
2,6,20,25,1.07038414478302,0.0722803920507431,2022,7,12") %>%
    mutate(start_dt = case_when(
      year == 2021 ~ ymd(paste("2021", start_month, "01", sep = "-")),
      year == 2022 ~ ymd(paste("2022", start_month, "01", sep = "-"))
    ),
    end_dt = case_when(
      year == 2021 ~ ceiling_date(ymd(paste("2021", end_month, "01", sep = "-")), unit = "month") - 1,
      year == 2022 ~ ceiling_date(ymd(paste("2022", end_month, "01", sep = "-")), unit = "month") - 1,
    ),
    end_month = ifelse(start_month == end_month, end_month + 1, end_month),
    end_month = ifelse(end_month > 12, 1, end_month),  # Wrap around to January if end_month exceeds 12
    start_dt1 = pmin(start_dt, end_dt),
    end_dt1   = pmax(start_dt, end_dt)) %>%
  arrange(start_dt1) %>%
  mutate(
    yy = row_number(),
    .by = c(year, num_months)
  )

# Create the ggplot

ggplot(data)  +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = start_dt1, xend = end_dt1,
    y = yy, yend = yy,
    color = factor(num_months)
  ), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL) +
  facet_grid(
    rows = vars(num_months), cols = vars(year),
    space = "free_y", scales = "free"
  ) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Number of Months", color = "Number of Months") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"), # Increase spacing between panels
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    x = lapply(
      unique(data$year),
      \(x) scale_x_date(
        date_labels = "%b",
        date_breaks = "1 month",
        expand = expansion(0, 0),
        limits = as.Date(paste0(x, c("-01-01", "-12-31")))
      )
    )
  )



I don't understand yet what you're seeing. I see 19 segments in 2021 and num_year 2:5, just like the data. Maybe you could share an image of your output that indicates the problem?

The last segment is num_months 2, year 2021 is three segments of three months each. The last two segments of num_months 3 and 4 is two segments overlapped.

I don't see that on my system. I added alpha = 0.5, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm") to the geom_segment() to show the endpoint and any overlaps, and I don't think I have that issue. Are you using the exact data and code that you have in the question? Fresh R session? You have ggh4x installed? What versions of ggplot2 and ggh4x are you using?

I think it may be due to the end_month being December, but I don't know how to fix that.

It seems the data prep you're using is not dealing correctly with periods that span years. Your 10th row of original data has start_month 12 and end_month 1, and it is represented in your processed data as a period from month 1 to month 12, instead of crossing years. Can you say more about how you want to handle those that span across more than one year?

I want to keep them under the same num_months, and showing the ending in the following year (2022).

I added this before your mutate(start_dt = case_when(... and added alpha = 0.5, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")) to the geom_segment for testing.
  mutate(across_yr = end_month < start_month) |>
  tidyr::uncount(weights = 1 + across_yr, .id = "copy") |>
  mutate(year = year - 1 + copy) |>
  mutate(end_month = if_else(copy == 1 & across_yr, 12, end_month),
         start_month = if_else(copy == 2, 1, start_month)) |>

The code notes the rows that cross a year, copies those into two rows, and adjust them so the first ends at Dec and the 2nd starts at Jan of the next year.


This works almost perfectly, but it assigns geom_segment() to another row in the following year, which is confusing in terms of data visualization.

Hmm. I suspect that will be tricky while each facet has free_y scale, since “position C” won’t be in the same position across facets. I need to noodle on how this could be done simply.

Thanks for the help! I came to a solution with your input.

With the incredible help of @Jon Spring, I came to the full solution.
data <- read_csv("country,num_months,start_month_year,end_month_year,B1,B1_p,year,start_month,end_month
2,1,6,6,3.3571016788482666,0.007681768853217363,2021,5,5
2,1,8,8,2.548985481262207,0.007373321335762739,2021,7,7
2,1,10,10,2.139772415161133,0.03452971577644348,2021,9,9
2,1,12,12,2.165775775909424,0.07796278595924377,2021,11,11
2,1,13,13,1.9506219625473022,0.09215697646141052,2021,12,12
2,1,23,23,2.7839596271514893,0.011407249607145786,2022,10,10
2,1,25,25,2.220555543899536,0.06181173026561737,2022,12,12
2,2,10,11,1.4871771335601807,0.06038494035601616,2021,9,10
2,2,12,13,2.0390524864196777,0.04265233874320984,2021,11,12
2,2,13,14,1.417211651802063,0.09348150342702866,2021,12,1
2,2,22,23,1.874699354171753,0.018470995128154755,2022,9,10
2,2,23,24,1.6757967472076416,0.028078539296984673,2022,10,11
2,3,6,8,1.334544062614441,0.05757715925574303,2021,5,7
2,3,8,10,1.2151446342468262,0.05723109096288681,2021,7,9
2,3,10,12,1.7102551460266113,0.03582938387989998,2021,9,11
2,3,11,13,1.6229373216629028,0.07926513999700546,2021,10,12
2,3,12,14,1.6802176237106323,0.04918825626373291,2021,11,1
2,3,13,15,1.417211651802063,0.09348150342702866,2021,12,2
2,3,22,24,1.3854548931121826,0.033461399376392365,2022,9,11
2,3,23,25,1.8822635412216187,0.01415294036269188,2022,10,12
2,4,8,11,1.1319600343704224,0.06593644618988037,2021,7,10
2,4,10,13,1.754726767539978,0.02880094014108181,2021,9,12
2,4,11,14,1.4533793926239014,0.08008415251970291,2021,10,1
2,4,12,15,1.6802176237106323,0.04918825626373291,2021,11,2
2,4,22,25,1.6274609565734863,0.011329303495585918,2022,9,12
2,5,6,10,1.0146392583847046,0.08948446065187454,2021,5,9
2,5,8,12,1.338212251663208,0.04161843657493591,2021,7,11
2,5,9,13,1.2212527990341187,0.0919371098279953,2021,8,12
2,5,10,14,1.5834165811538696,0.03494146466255188,2021,9,1
2,5,11,15,1.4533793926239014,0.08008415251970291,2021,10,2
2,5,12,16,1.4284441471099854,0.0697392150759697,2021,11,3
2,5,21,25,1.2466250658035278,0.035289958119392395,2022,8,12
2,6,6,11,0.9881601333618164,0.08719704300165176,2021,5,10
2,6,8,13,1.438501238822937,0.032221969217061996,2021,7,12
2,6,9,14,1.16400945186615,0.09187468141317368,2021,8,1
2,6,10,15,1.5834165811538696,0.03494146466255188,2021,9,2
2,6,11,16,1.294316291809082,0.09792502969503403,2021,10,3
2,6,12,17,1.4204859733581543,0.0546354204416275,2021,11,4
2,6,20,25,1.07038414478302,0.0722803920507431,2022,7,12") %>%
  mutate(
    across_yr = end_month < start_month,
    segment_id = row_number()
  ) %>%
  tidyr::uncount(weights = 1 + across_yr, .id = "copy") %>%
  mutate(
    year = year - 1 + copy,
    end_month = if_else(copy == 1 & across_yr, 12, end_month),
    start_month = if_else(copy == 2, 1, start_month),
    start_dt = case_when(
      year == 2021 ~ ymd(paste("2021", start_month, "01", sep = "-")),
      year == 2022 ~ ymd(paste("2022", start_month, "01", sep = "-"))
    ),
    end_dt = case_when(
      year == 2021 ~ ceiling_date(ymd(paste("2021", end_month, "01", sep = "-")), unit = "month") - 1,
      year == 2022 ~ ceiling_date(ymd(paste("2022", end_month, "01", sep = "-")), unit = "month") - 1,
    )
  ) %>%
  arrange(start_dt) %>%
  group_by(segment_id) %>%
  mutate(yy = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(data) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = start_dt, xend = end_dt,
    y = yy, yend = yy,
    color = factor(num_months)
  ), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#a36361", "#d3a29d", "#e8b298", "#eecc8c", "#bdd1c5", "#9eaba2")) +
  facet_grid(
    rows = vars(num_months), cols = vars(year),
    space = "free_y", scales = "free"
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Month",
    y = "Number of Months",
    color = "Number of Months"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"), # Increase spacing between panels
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    x = lapply(
      unique(data$year),
      \(x) scale_x_date(
        date_labels = "%b",
        date_breaks = "1 month",
        expand = expansion(0, 0),
        limits = as.Date(paste0(x, c("-01-01", "-12-31")))
      )
    )
  )

This is how it looks like:

